# Do we need Optional ifNotPresent for use in the middle of chain?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

There are so many questions and threads about `Optional` API but I didn't found any for my case.

For example, I need first check emptiness of an `Optional` variable, for logging purpose, and then
check the value, if presents, with some predicate. Whatever check fails, I need to throw an exception.

Below is my real workaround for that

```java
SomeValue value = someOptional.orElseThrow(() -> {
    log.debug("nothing here");
    return new NothingSpecialHereException();
});

if (!value.isSpecial()) {
    log.debug("something here, but not special");
    throw new NothingSpecialHereException();
}
```

When I was looking for an alternative solution for that, I tried something like that

```java
SomeValue value = someOptional
    .filter(SomeValue::isSpecial)
    .orElseThrow(() -> {
        log.debug("nothing special here"); // but this case for both "no value" and "value is not special"
        return new NothingSpecialHereException();
    });
```

I know that there's no any built-in solution for this situation in Java, but seems like I missing something like:

```java
SomeValue value = someOptional
   .ifNotPresent(() -> log.debug("nothing here")) // that method returns Optional for further invocatons
   .filter(val -> {
      if (!val.isSpecial()) {
          log.debug("something here, but not special");
          return false;
      }
      return true;
   })
   .orElseThrow(NothingSpecialHereException::new);
```

This is not the first time when I miss something like `ifNotPresent` or `else*` methods for use in the middle of pipe, not in the end. IMO sometimes that approach might be more readable, for example

```java
optional
    .map(...)
    .filter(...)
    .ifEmpty(...) // do smth after filter, maybe even throw
    .map(...) // and continue processing
```

Maybe anyone encountered same problem? Or maybe I missed some better solution? Maybe there's a library that provides solutions for that?

Comment: Just use ordinary code instead of an `Optional` chain.

Comment: @Holger, honestly, I agree with you. And I use `if null` pattern really often in such cases. But I'm really tired of that boilerplate - `var foo = repo.find(...).orElse(null)`, or even worse `if (opt.isPresent())`.

Comment: Your first variant looks like the best trade-off, `SomeValue value = someOptional.orElseThrow(() -> { … });` to utilize the Optional API where it makes sense, followed by ordinary code using `value`.

Comment: True, but you may agree that the second and third examples look more aesthetic. At the moment I'm looking through Vavr library, from [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62033622/9690114) answer. Maybe I'll find something

Comment: What you actually want, is some kind of *Either* value like existing in other languages, that can hold a value or a specific exception. To some degree, `CompletableFuture` works that way. Once a future has been completed exceptionally, all chained operations will fail for the same reason. So the final stage will contain either, an end result value or an exception stemming from the failed stage.

Answer (score 1):

The JDK `Optional` includes (since Java 9 only, which was a major oversight in Java 8) `ifPresentOrElse`, which could be used with a no-op first argument. Alternately, the [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/) library is a set of functional wrappers that is slightly more consistent than `Optional` and provides additional useful wrappers such as `Try` at the cost of having an extra dependency.

Comment: As I know, `ifPresentOrElse` returns `void` that makes it impossible to use in the middle of pipe. P.S. thanks for lib =)

Answer (score 0):

```java
SomeValue value = Optional.ofNullable(someValue.isPresent()?       
                   someValue.filter(SomeValue::isSpecial)
                  .orElseThrow(NothingSpecialHereException::new)
                  :null)
                  .orElseThrow(NothingHereException::new) ;
```

If someValue is present then the value can be set to special value or throw exception NothingSpecialHereException else if someValue is not present it will give Optinal it will check if null (someValue is not present) Throw NothingHereException.

Exception "NothingSpecialHereException" thrown only if value is present and not special.

Exception "NothingHereException" thrown only if value is not present.

Comment: Your code style is hard to read, but I've got your point. However, for me it seems to be even more robust approach than my first example. Plus in my case there's no need  to throw two different exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments! I've checked out Vavr `Option` and Guava `Optional` APIs.

Guava `Optional` is even less rich in methods than Java `Optional`, so this is not a solution.

What I've found is the Vavr `onEmpty` [method](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.2/io/vavr/control/Option.html#onEmpty-java.lang.Runnable-) of `Option` class, that executes `Runnable` if the Option value is empty.

```java
SomeValue value = Option.ofOptional(someOptional)
    .onEmpty(() -> log.debug("nothing here"))
    .filter(val -> {
      if (!val.isSpecial()) {
          log.debug("something here, but not special");
          return false;
      }
      return true;
   })
   .getOrElseThrow(NothingHereException::new);
```

That example displays one of debug messages and throws exception only in one place. Looks a lot better.

However, Vavr is a big library with own collections, functional interfaces and monads like above. This is a big dependency for a project and it is hardly will be implemented in my project or any other long-time-existed project just for new fancy `Optional` replacement.

Plus, Vavr's `Option` does'nt have something like `onEmptyThrow`, so it's not so perfect =).

This thread is still open for suggestions, but now for Java 8 workaround I think [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62033101/do-we-need-optional-ifnotpresent-for-use-in-the-middle-of-chain#comment109728652_62033101) may be considered as answer.

### UPDATE

Seems like I've found the best solution for problems like that.
Few days ago I found [lombok's @ExtensionMethod annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/ExtensionMethod) that makes possible solutions like below

```
class Extensions {
    public static <T, E extends Throwable> Optional<T> ifNotPresentThrow(Optional<T> opt, Supplier<E> exceptionSupplier) throws E {
        if (!opt.isPresent()) {
            throw exceptionSupplier.get();
        }
        return opt;
    }

}

@ExtensionMethod(Extensions.class)
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // assume there is someNullable variable

        // instead of writing
        Extensions.ifNotPresentThrow(Optional.ofNullable(someNullable), NothingHereException::new)
                .map(...);

        // I can write
        Optional.ofNullable(someNullable)
                .ifNotPresentThrow(NothingHereException::new)
                .map(...); // now possible to continue if optional present
    }
}
```

With that Kotlin-like extension methods it's possible to add any method to Optional's API. Lombok will just transform second variant into first during compilation.

However, this feature is experimental (seems like forever) and has possible bugs and decompiled bytecode looks pretty dirty (with various unnecessary local variables, etc.)